# Is Avatar referencing the Bible?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

So according to the Bible, Satan will get his power from the kingdom of air.

Is The Last Airbender somehow based on the Bible, or are the uses of the term *air* just a coincidence?

> And you were dead in the trespasses and sins in which you once walked, following the course of this world, **following the prince of the power of the air**, the spirit that is now at work in the sons of disobedience—among whom we all once lived in the passions of our flesh, carrying out the desires of the body and the mind, and were by nature children of wrath, like the rest of mankind. (Ephesians 2:1-3)

Comment: Pretty sure that's just coincidence.

Comment: considering the 'prince of the power of the air' is generally considered to be demonic or the Satan himself - it is unlikely that Airbender referenced it intentionally

Comment: There are many ways of describing demonic powers in the bible. Searching until you find one that matches a movie in which an evil power is at work is pretty easy. It would be very strange if nothing would ever match at all. Also in this context a 'prince' means in the greek a principal of power or a spiritual being with power, not directly Satan.

Comment: The elements in the avatar word are inspired by the [five classical elements in Hinduism/Buddhism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_element) which are: bhūmi (earth), ap or jala (water), tejas or agni (fire), marut, *vayu or pavan (air or wind)* and vyom or shunya (space or zero)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

[*Avatar* is based on](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Influences_on_the_Avatar_series) Greek classical elements, Chinese traditional martial arts, world cultures (but not notably Western), and *The Hero of a Thousand Faces*.

Also, Airbending refers to the the ability to control *literal* air. [The power of air referenced in the scripture in your question is *figurative*](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/18794/17963).

It's not uncommon to take biblical phrases out of context when developing a story, but we have nothing to indicate that's the case with *Avatar*. The belief systems in the world of *Avatar* are not similar to Christianity or Abrahamic religions in general. So, to have the titular character be a reference to a Christian villain makes little sense.